# Compare two associative array and combine both data in php

Tags: php

Unable to get difference associative array with combined data.
Those value which is not found in array:4 should be combined with array:2 as like below with count 0:

```
2=>array:2[
"value" => Occupation
"count" => 0
]
```

What I have already tried

```
$datas=[];
        foreach($data as $arrayIndex=>$element){
            $match = false;
            foreach($domains as $key=>$elementToMatch){
                if($element['value'] != $elementToMatch ){
                    $match = true;
                    $counts = ['value'=>$elementToMatch,'count'=>0];
                }
                if($match == true) {
                    break;
                }

            }

            if($match) {
                array_push($datas,$counts);
            }
        }
```

Please help
[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack...!!! You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Do you want the extra value present in array:4 to be added to array:2 with the count 0, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$values = array_column($array2, 'value');
foreach ($array4 as $item) {
    if ( ! in_array($item, $values, true)) {
        $array2[] = [
            'value' => $item,
            'count' => 0
        ];
    }
}
```

I just used [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to get the value of all the `value` of the array:2 and check if all the value from array:4 are present in that data using [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

If not present add the missing value with count 0 to array:2